# Odoo change selected selection on python file

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have a model which has a selection field like you can show below

```
task_type = fields.Selection([
            ('product', 'Product'),
            ('document', 'Document'),
            ('issue', 'Issue'),
            ('child','Child'),
            ('other','Other')],
           'Task Type', copy=False, 
                help="Let user choose the type of each task:\n"
                        "- Product :\n"
                        "  Development of new system, apps, report, ...\n"
                        "- Document : \n"
                        "  The deliverable is a document, presentation, invoice, sales, slides, ...\n"
                         "- Issue : \n"
                        "  There is an issue or task to solve related to other task\n"
                         "- Child : \n"
                        "  Used for children task\n"
                         "- Other  \n"  )
```

My problem is how can i change selected value of this selection programmatically inside .py file?.

I have tried like this but it didn't work.

```
task_type = "child"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update that record use write method like,

```
 Partner.write([partner.id], {'name': "MyCompany"})
```

Here Partner is an object of res.partner model.